# I want to change the time automatically when i select the drop down option

Tags: jquery, select, html-select

```js
$(function() {
  var select = $('select').val;
  if (select = 1) {
    $("#selectedTime").val("11:00 AM");
  }
});
else {
  $("#selectedTime").val("8:00 PM");
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="" class="select"> 
  <option value="">Select</option> 
  <option value="1">lunch</option> 
  <option value="2">Dinner</option> 
</select>
<input type="time" id="selectedTime">
```

Comment: Firstly, please make an effort to format your questions properly. Before I edited it, this was completely unreadable. Secondly your code has some syntax issues - check the console.

Comment: And reading the documentation about event binding will also be helpful

Comment: Firstly you if statement is wrong. Second, you need get the value in the select tag, not in the options tags because you want to get the value in the selected option, and the select tag is the responsable to get the current option tag values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things here:

First, use the `change` event handler for the select picker to trigger the change. Second, make sure you use a [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) time format for setting the value. Third, you had some syntax wrong in some of your code (mis-placed braces):

```js
$(function() {
  var select = $('select').val;
  $( "select.select" ).change(function() {
  // Check input( $( this ).val() ) for validity here
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
      $("#selectedTime").val("11:00:00");
    } else {
      $("#selectedTime").val("08:00:00");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="" class="select"> 
  <option value="">Select</option> 
  <option value="1">lunch</option> 
  <option value="2">Dinner</option> 
</select>
<input type="time" id="selectedTime">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few problems here:

- There's a random `});` in the middle of your code causing a syntax error
- `val` isn't a property, it's a function, so should be `.val()`
- `val()` also returns a string, so you should compare to `'1'`, not `1`
- `=` is used for setting values. `==` or `===` is used for comparison
- The time values you set should not have `AM` or `PM`, and should be in the format `00:00`, not `0:00`.

Finally, your code only runs once when the page loads. You instead need to hook to the `change` event of the `select`. You can then execute your code and update the `val()` of the time input, something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.select').change(function() {
    var select = $(this).val();
    if (select === '1') {
      $("#selectedTime").val("11:00");
    } else {
      $("#selectedTime").val("08:00");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="" class="select"> 
  <option value="">Select</option> 
  <option value="1">lunch</option> 
  <option value="2">Dinner</option> 
</select>
<input type="time" id="selectedTime">
```

Comment: Thank you Rory McCrossan  , you solved my problem it  worked for me.  actually  i have one week experience  using j query . so that's why typed wrong syntax.